# Dropbox API OAuth 2 with WinHttp

Tags: dropbox-api

So I am trying to authorize myself using the WinHttp API and I am able to connect perfectly fine but when I do my WinHttpSendRequest I get back a 400 error and it is telling me that i am not passing a client_id.

this is my full request

WinHttpSendRequest( hRequestAuth,WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,0,authUserParams,strlen(authUserParams),strlen(authUserParams),0);

where authUserParams is

"{\"response_type\":\"code\",\"client_id\":\"k6saup8e89guy8d\",\"state\":\"bKiknxPEkcfQC6r\",\"force_reapprove\":false,\"disable_signup\":false}"

Am I not supposed to send this as data? or does this go into a Authorization header

Comment: Are you calling [/oauth2/authorize](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#oa2-authorize)? That's a web endpoint, not an API endpoint. You're supposed to send the user there in a browser to authorize your app.

Comment: Yes i am using that endpoint

Answer (score 0):

The [/oauth2/authorize](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#oa2-authorize) endpoint is a web endpoint, not an API endpoint, so you wouldn't be submitting the HTTPS request to it directly. Instead, you should send the user there in a browser.

For example, using your sample values, the URL should look like:

https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=k6saup8e89guy8d&state=bKiknxPEkcfQC6r&force_reapprove=false&disable_signup=false